# I want the radius of my button to change back on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with the radius of my button. When I click on it the radius of it goes from 50% to 0 so it looks fluently with the panel, but when I mouseleave it doesn't change back.

I've been searching the web for a few days now but I can't find anything on my specific problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flip").click(function() {
        $("#panel").fadeToggle("fast");
        if($(this).is(".radius")) {
            $(this).removeClass("radius"); 
            return;
        }
        $(this).addClass("radius").siblings().removeClass("radius");    
   });
});

$("#Left").mouseleave(function() {
   $("#panel").hide();
});
```

I'm a complete noob at javascript as you can see haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this? It's a bit hard to tell without a running example of your code, throw it up on jsfiddle if you can.

```
$("#Left").mouseleave(function() { 
    $("#panel").hide();
    $('#flip').addClass('radius').siblings().addClass('radius');
});
```

Comment: thank you very much ! this is exactly what i wanted, i was thinking way to hard.. Much appreciated !!

Comment: @Raymond no worries mate, if that's answered your question feel free to mark this as the answer and close it off.